# Create summary table to show the percentage of customer per agent in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the original table as below and I want to summarize the percentage of customers for each agent every month in power bi.

I tried the DAX before, can you tell me know what's wrong?

```
Customer%_Table =
SUMMARIZE (
    'Original Table',
    'Original Table'[Period],
    'Original Table'[Agent],
    "Customer%", CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Original Table'[Customer] )
            / CALCULATE (
                SUM ( 'Original Table'[Customer] ),
                ALL ( 'Original Table'[Period] )
            )
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you mean to divide by all agents, not all periods, in your Result Table, so put

```
ALL ( 'Original Table'[Agent] )
```

instead of

```
ALL ( 'Original Table'[Period] )
```

in your second `CALCULATE` or else specify the context you want to *keep* using

```
ALLEXCEPT ( 'Original Table', 'Original Table'[Period] )
```